# Which one of these implementations is more appropriate for my REST api?

Tags: data-structures, rest, object-oriented-design, model

#### Background

So I have a REST API that allows for client applications to access and manipulate users' data.

I'm in the process of writing an Objective-C class for simple utilization of this REST API, but I'm stuck between two methods of implementation.

#### Method 1

```
class MYClient
    string username
    string password
    methods for using GET, PUT, POST, DELETE on questions
    // questions are dictionaries with 'title' and 'body' strings
```

#### Method 2

```
class MYUser
    string username
    string password
    array  tokens
class MYToken
    string title
    string body

// classes inherently sync themselves to the server in their initializers, setters, and getters
```

#### Questions

- Is there one that is more appropriate for use in (for example) iOS apps?
- Is there one that is more appropriate in general?
- What are the distinct benefits of Method 1 over Method 2 and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is going to be the number and granularity of HTTP requests that go over the network.

Method 1 is going to send fewer, larger requests that perform operations on a batch operations.  Method 2 is going to send more, smaller requests every time an object's property is modified.

Method 1 is also going to give you the ability to queue up a bunch of changes client-side then give the user the option to cancel or commit the changes.  Method 2 is going to commit each change individually and immediately.  If the user cancels or undoes an operation then a second request will be needed to undo the changes server side.

Based purely on their own merits, I prefer Method 1.  However, which one is more appropriate for your app depends on the functionality you are looking for.

**UPDATE:** In Method 1, `MyClient.DoSomething()` does not have to "do something" to one object at a time.  Say you want to create 5 new `MyUser` objects.  You don't have to call `MyClient.Create(newMyUser)` 5 times, once for each new `MyUser` object.  Your `Create()` method can take an array of objects and all 5 new `MyUser` objects can be sent to the server in the body of a single POST.  Similarly, say you want to update the `UserName` and `Password` properties on the same `MyUser` object.  Method 2 would result in 2 requests, each sending a copy of the whole `MyUser` object for each property change.  Method 1 would allow you to make the changes to both properties client side then send the `MyUser` object with both property changes to the server in a single PUT.  In both scenarios, Method 1 gives you the option to delay pushing changes to the server until you call the appropriate method in `MyClient` and pass in the changed objects.  In Method 2, changes to each object are pushed to the server immediately and individually.

Comment: Any chance you could expound on the queueing concepts, as this is not something that I'm entirely aware of / was considering :)